# Azure Function App deployed to different service plan not working

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, servicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus Trigger that has been working both locally and in our Azure environment. Unfortunately, I had been deploying this to a consumption service plan, and I need it on a regular service plan. All deployments have been via Visua Studio.
No problem, right? I deployed the exact same code to a different service plan (in the same resource group) and it does not work. Messages are not being taken off of the queue.
At first I thought it was a connectivity or configuration issue, but then I noticed that the function isn't listed under "Functions."
I realize that the difference service plan itself isn't likely to be the cause, but I can't figure out what else has changed. I have also redeployed this code using the Consumption Plan and the trigger works perfectly.

Thanks for the advice.
I've just checked the debug console for both versions and there's obviously a lot missing from the one that isn't working. Bummer that VS said the deployment was successful. Btw, the bad version is "running." I guess I'll have to deploy again with some verbose output to see if that helps.

Comment: Did you get any error message when publishing to regular service plan? You can go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` then navigate to D:\home\site\wwwroot folder to see whether your function is uploaded. And check whether you have added service bus connection string to Application settings.

Comment: Are you using beta version? (Look in app settings in the portal - If the key 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' is set to 'beta'). If you are, make sure you are using 32-bit. I had the same issue last week and spent 3 hours on the phone with MS before we figured this out.

Comment: @daver Do you get any further?